# Call a list of functions with the same argument in ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Suppose I have a list of functions that I want to call with the same argument and get a list of results. Here's my [setup](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?let%20input%20%3D%202%0Alet%20fns%20%3D%20%5Badd%282%29%2C%20add%283%29%2C%20add%284%29%5D%0A%0Amap%28x%20%3D%3E%20x%28input%29%2C%20fns%29%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20what%20I%20want%0A%2F%2Fmap%28flip%28call%29%28input%29%2C%20fns%29%20%2F%2F%20this%20also%20works%20and%20prduces%20%5B4%2C%205%2C%206%5D%0A%2F%2Fmap%28call%28__%2C%20input%29%2C%20fns%29%20%2F%2F%20this%20doesn%27t%20work%21%20Why%3F):

```js
let input = 2
let fns = [add(2), add(3), add(4)]

map(x => x(input), fns)
// this is what I want. Outputs [4, 5, 6]
```

But I don't quite like the use of the arrow function (purely for stylistic reasons), so I wanted to rewrite it as,

```js
map(call(__, input), fns)
// this doesn't work and produces [[Function],[Function],[Function]]
```

I can't figure out why `x => x(input)` isn't equivalent to `call(__, input)`. My thinking is, `call(__, input)` will return a function that will call its first argument with `input`.

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong? My hunch is that I have misunderstood the use of `__`. And how do I use `call` or some other built-in function to elegantly write this?

I also tried,

```js
// this also works and produces [4, 5, 6]
map(flip(call)(input), fns)
```

But this also does not sit well with me due to stylistic reasons. I feel like I am shoehorning something with `flip`, and I also don't like the consecutive function calls `(...)(...)`.

Comment: Arrow functions are the future. Learn them, use them. Can you add the code of the add(...) function?

Comment: @aepifano: I know them. I use them all the time and have nothing against them. I just can't figure out why those two things aren't equivalent and that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [R.juxt](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt):

> juxt applies a list of functions to a list of values.

```js
const { add, juxt } = R

const input = 2
const fns = [add(2), add(3), add(4)]

const addTo = juxt(fns)

const result = addTo(input)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Incredible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ori Drori showed that `juxt` will do what you want.

As to why `call` doesn't work... honestly, it's perhaps the worst-designed function in all of Ramda.  (I'm one of the founders of Ramda and I think I wrote it, so I'm not insulting anyone but myself.)

There is very, very little need for it.  Why would you write `call(fn, 1, 2)` when you could just write `fn(1, 2)`.  Currying doesn't work properly since it's variadic, which is itself a problem.  Even the example is pretty unclear, mostly because it's hard to *find* any meaningful example.

I would just skip using it, personally.

> But I don't quite like the use of the arrow function (purely for stylistic reasons), so I wanted to rewrite it as,

From the comments, I'm assuming that you don't mean arrow functions as opposed to function declarations or function expressions, but rather that you'd prefer to write this point-free.  A suggestion: use a point-free style where it makes your code more readable, but skip it when it doesn't; don't make a fetish out of it.

Here `juxt([add(2), add(3), add(4)])` seems fine, so long as `juxt` (short for `juxtapose`) makes sense to you.  But often enough, pushing for point-free seems to cause more harm than good.

> I also tried,
>
> ```
> // this also works and produces [4, 5, 6]
> map(flip(call)(input), fns)
> ```
>
> But this also does not sit well with me due to stylistic reasons. I feel like I am shoehorning something with `flip`,

I tend to agree.  `flip` is not a wonderful solution to nearly any problem.  But I usually like the placeholder even less.  There's just no satisfying me!

> and I also don't like the consecutive function calls `(...)(...)`.

Here I disagree.  I've switched my own code to an almost-universally fully-curried style.  If that involves multiple consecutive function calls and the dreaded parentheses butt, so be it.  I simply find it easier to work with and to reason about.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. As for usability of `call`, I think anything in the form of `fn(<unknownArg>, knownArg)` would benefit with the placeholder. But then again we repeatedly see that in Ramda, data comes last and if the functions were designed that way we would never need the placeholder in the first place.

Comment: @sampathsris: Agreed.  But because of the poor design of `call`, we can't do that, since we have no idea how many arguments there will be.  `flip` still works because it only cares about the first two arguments, passing the rest through.